GCP Dataform API, Query Directory Contents
I am trying to query directories and files that are located in spesific directories in GCP Dataform. I used query_directory_contents and got files and directories for a spesific workspace.
My code:
from google.cloud import dataform_v1beta1 as dataform
df_client = dataform.DataformClient()
workspace = "projects/*/locations/*/repositories/*/workspaces/ws_test"
contents = df_client.query_directory_contents(request=dataform.QueryDirectoryContentsRequest(workspace=workspace))

And I got this result:
QueryDirectoryContentsPager<directory_entries {
  file: ".gitignore"
}
directory_entries {
  file: "dataform.json"
}
directory_entries {
  directory: "definitions"
}
directory_entries {
  directory: "node_modules"
}
directory_entries {
  file: "package-lock.json"
}
directory_entries {
  file: "package.json"
}
>

So now, I want to query directories and files that are located in definitions directory. However, I couldn't find a way for this.
I also tried query_repository_directory_contents but it didn't work for me.
Could anyone help me?
Edit:
Dataform/searchFiles API endpoint provides me what I want. My code is:
endpoint = f"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/*/locations/*/repositories/*/workspaces/ws_test:searchFiles"
token = "ya29.a0Ad52N..." # I got it from Google Cloud SDK via "gcloud auth print-access-token"
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer ' + token}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
response = response.json()

And response is:
{'searchResults': [{'file': {'path': '.gitignore'}},
  {'file': {'path': 'dataform.json'}},
  {'directory': {'path': 'definitions'}},
  {'directory': {'path': 'definitions/folder1'}},
  {'directory': {'path': 'definitions/folder1/folder11'}},
  {'file': {'path': 'definitions/folder1/folder11/file111.sqlx'}},
  {'directory': {'path': 'definitions/folder1/folder12'}},
  {'file': {'path': 'definitions/folder1/folder12/file121.sqlx'}},
.
.

However, in order to run this I had to get token from Google Cloud SDK via gcloud auth print-access-token. To be able to use default user credentials I should use client libraries (I guess) and searchFiles isn't in those.

Hi @Redhill, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

@DhirajSingh thanks for your comment, I created a new issue on the issue tracker. Btw in addition to my first message, added some different informations about dataform API. I had to get token manually, do you know that can I automatize it? (I searched documents again but I didn't find.)
